# Disable "Open Executable File" dialog in Firefox 63.0

Tags: firefox, download

After the latest update Firefox began to open an annoying "Open Executable File?" dialog every time I try to open any downloaded file, be it PDF, ZIP, you name it.  I'm not a baby, I know what I download and the consequences of opening these files, how do I tell Firefox to shut up and skip this annoying dialog?

Comment: This may help: https://superuser.com/questions/166323/

Comment: The best thing is my `browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen` is already set to `false`, still the dialog appears.

Comment: I have the same problem with Firefox 66. I strongly suspect this is because I'm saving files to a NTFS partition which has the executable flag set by default thereby leading to the annoying firefox warning. See also: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1005948 The alertOnEXEOpen also does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Open `about:config` in your browser bar and set boolean `browser.download.skipConfirmLaunchExecutable` to `true`.